# Enable scroll when user scroll by placing finger on richtextbox in winrt phone application

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, componentone

I have a page with too many richtext boxes and when scrolling if user place his finger on top of rtb form doesn't scroll, user has to place his finger on empty place.

Is there any possible way to stop that behavior?

I am working on a winrt universal application, question is specifically for windows phone project.

**UPDATED:**

Actually I am using component one library, and for some reason I want to use its richtextbox control just like a richtextblock. Below is xaml:

```
<as:C1RichTextBox x:Name="rtbBox" Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent"  
      BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Xaml:C1NagScreen.Nag="True" IsReadOnly="True" IsTapEnabled="False" DisableSelection="True" HideCaret="True"/>
      <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="Auto" Background="Transparent"></Grid>

     <Image Margin="0,0,0,20" Width="200" Grid.Row="2" Source="{Binding InstallationInstructionPic1Bind}"/>
      <as:C1RichTextBox x:Name="rtb1Detail" Grid.Row="3" Background="Transparent" 
          BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Xaml:C1NagScreen.Nag="True" 
          NavigationMode="Always"
          />
```

These border and background properties are just to make its look more like a textblock, and to stop editing I have marked isReadonly property to true in .cs file. I have also placed transparent gridview above my first rtb to scroll and that works but there are some links in some of the rtb's and if I place grid view on top of all rtb I'll not be able to click these links. Ask anything if its not clear.

Comment: If you could show us some code? Where are the `RichTextboxes` placed?

Comment: updated my question, tell me if you need more.